# pop-up code not working for Safari browser

Tags: javascript

```
function compareDate() {
  var d1 = Date.parse(document.frm_date.txt_dt1.value);
  var d2 = Date.parse(document.frm_date.txt_dt2.value);

  if (d1 != d2) {
    alert ("Code not matched");
  } 
  else if (d1 == d2) {
    $('.popup').hide();
  } 
  return true;
}
```

this is script i am using.. it is working fine for other browsers just not working for safari

```
<input type="text" required class="form-control" style="display:none" value=CSS-2018 id=txt_dt1 name=txt_dt1>
<input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Code Here" id=txt_dt2 name=txt_dt2>
</div>

<input type=button value=SUBMIT onclick=compareDate() class="btn btn-primary form-control" style="background-color:black">
```

Please help

Comment: Any one please help

Comment: This is my form code i am using

Comment: Post essential components of your question in the question itself, not in comments.

Comment: "Not working" is ***not helpful***.